# Can I attach an image to an FBDialog?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm writing an iOS app that produces an image, and we'd like the user to be able to post that image to their Facebook wall using the standard facebook dialog.

The Facebook iOS SDK provides a dialog for posting to a user's wall, using the `dialog:withParams:andDelegate:` method, and you can provide the URL of a picture in the params argument.  However, that's no good to me - I want to send off an image that exists only on the phone.

The SDK also provides a way to post an image to a user's wall, using the `requestWithGraphPath:andParams:andHttpMethod:andDelegate:` method.  But that's no good to me either - I want to use the standard dialog.

Is there a way for me to send the image data with an FBDialog?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a photo upload first, with a graph call to `'/me/photos'` - this will be in an album that your app will have to create, not an existing one (unless your app created it).

That will return you the photo id, which you can then hit the graph again with a call to that specific id: `'https://graph.facebook.com/RETURNING_PHOTO)ID'`

This will return name, picture, source, link (and a bunch of other stuff) - you can then use the picture (which is a thumbnail) in your wall post as the picture and add the URL to the source (big image) or use the link to the photo in the album (link) inside your message text.

Hope this helps,
-J

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the photo upload either creates its own story (which I don't want) or needs to be authorised separately by the user (which I also don't want).